# java.net.ConnectException timed out

Tags: java, exception

I'm using NetBeans with Java. I'm trying to extract data from a website that needs logging, I'm go into an account I extract data and then go into another, my code is working but always after a while I get: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect. 
    I'm using Apache HttpClient. If I use the code works on another site without the exception, if someone could help me ... Thanks.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at navegadorsite.NavegadorSite.openPage(NavegadorSite.java:80)
    at navegadorsite.NavegadorSite.main(NavegadorSite.java:174)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to increase the time that your socket waits till it receives a data from the other site, you can call following static methods before making your actual connection:

```
HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 30000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30000);`.
```

The above calls specifies a 30 second timeout for both your connection establishment and socket readings.

Comment: how I solved: 
I created a try-catch making the catch "come back" to try and it worked, thanks anyway